# webpack: command not found after npm install webpack -g

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, installation

Weird behaviour on my OSX Yosemite: from one day to another all my node modules installed by `npm install -g` were not found via the Terminal.

I'm not sure if this is due to my node v4.0.0 install the day before.

Comment: I've found a trick that partially answered to the issue : when you run npm root, you should get your current working directory. That’s where npm puts your modules when you install them. But when you run npm root -g, you should get something like /usr/local/lib/node_modules.

If you get your current working directory in both cases, you have to update the path with the following command **npm config set prefix /usr/local**
credits to [gabriel ghe] (http://gabrielghe.github.io/javascript/2015/04/29/globally-installed-node-modules-not-found/)

Comment: Mine was actually pointing at an old version of node as I've been using NVM to switch between versions on different projects.

Comment: This problem is seen on Windows too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally also used NVM for multiple NodeJS versions management and everything went back under control.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
echo $(npm config get prefix)/bin
```

you will get STRING, which should include to your .bash_profile such way

```
export PATH=$PATH:STRING
```

Answer (score 5):

Install it globally

```
npm i -g webpack
```

If you will work with webpack, install webpack-dev-server too

```
npm i -g webpack-dev-server
```

After I Install this two command I also found errors when run the

```
webpack
```

command so I figure out the problem by changing the **version** of webpack so I Install

```
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22
```

and every thing work fine for me.

I recommend you first learn a bit about **npm** and then **webpack**. You will struggle a lot. but finally you will find the right destination.

Comment: thank you, it worked for me on mac, quick and easy!

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is in your ./node_modules/.bin/ folder so instead of giving just webpack as the command try this.

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

> You have the npm bin command to get the folder where npm will install
>   executables.
>
> You can use the scripts property of your package.json to use webpack
>   from this directory which will be exported.

```
"scripts": {   "scriptName": "webpack --config etc..." } For example:
"scripts": {   "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js" } You can
```

then run it with:

> `npm run build` Or even with arguments:
>
> `npm run build -- <args>`
>
> This allow you to have you webpack.config.js in the root folder of
>   your project without having webpack globally installed or having your
>   webpack configuration in the node_modules folder.